# iOS - Disable Alamofire Cache parameters

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire

does Alamofire also cache request parameters?

after doing a login request, i open my cache.db and it reveals my username and password parameters.

is it default for alamofire to cache request parameters or it's just my misconfiguration ?

is there any way to disable caching just for the parameters. because currently i enable caching just for .GET request since it doesn't have parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can disable any kind of caching as below,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let emptyCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
    URLCache.shared = emptyCache

    return true
}
```

Comment: doesn't it also disable caching for response ? what i want is just disable caching for the request parameters (json body).

Comment: I should've written "disable all kind of". Yes, it will disable both. I can't think of a way for disabling only for response. But you can dig down to find some way.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable cache in alamofire as below.

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```